# Java `NoSuchMethodException` but method exists - No reflections in code

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I compiled code in NetBeans (using Java 8) with this small parts of code:

```
private void initMessages(ConfigurationSection sec)
{
    if (sec == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (Message msg : Message.values())
    {
        msg.setMsg(sec.getString(msg.name(), msg.getMsg()));
    }
}
```

Class `com.gmail.bukkitsmerf.freebuild.configuration.Config` lines from 33 to 43

and:

```
public void setMsg(String... msg)
{
    this.msg = StringUtils.join(msg, "\n");
}
```

Class (enum) `com.gmail.bukkitsmerf.freebuild.configuration.Message` lines from 45-48

I decompiled code using "SecureTeam Java Decompiler" and everything exist like in original source.

But when I trying to use it...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.gmail.bukkitsmerf.freebuild.configuration.Message.setMsg(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.gmail.bukkitsmerf.freebuild.configuration.Config.initMessages(Config.java:41) ~[?:?]
```

why? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Did you try "clean" and "build" and then run it again?

Comment: @libik works... meh, NetBeans is so buggy, but my PC is too slow for Eclipse.

Comment: But why? why it has good code after decompile?

Comment: It compiles only files that does change and their dependencies, it is faster (especially in bigger projects), but sometimes it can do it bad...

Comment: @libik but then after decompile it should have wrong code?

Comment: Not sure what exactly means "after decompile" :).

Comment: @libik I open .jar file using http://secureteam.net/Java-Decompiler.aspx